Resampling calibration data
Is it appropriate to resample a calibration dataset, or should the class distribution be consistent with the observed data?

One frequently mentioned observation  is "class imbalance is not a problem" https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he (but there are many more related questions here and on Cross Validated).
